# Is it immoral to expect uncompensated contribution to the university from doctorate students?

Tags: phd, ethics

In every university that I know, doctorate (and very commonly master's) students are expected to do a number of things which I would categorize as work, related to the operation of the faculty, such as:

1. correcting exams
2. supervising exams
3. supervising undergraduates in lab exercises, answering questions, usually organizing groups and  lab exams
4. teaching lectures on the methodology for exercises of a course
5. various errands for the professor (I won't get into detail in this, as it's clearly immoral in my opinion)

From what I have heard, those practices are common in Greece.  Every PhD student that I know has no official salary from the university, and may get paid from certain research funds for particular projects that he has to complete/contribute to from outside sources. According to the regulations in Greek universities, Master's and above students are obliged to provide "auxiliary work" without this being specified further.

Given the fact that correcting exams is actual work, isn't it immoral to do it without monetary compensation?

Comment: Sadly, immoral or moral, it happens (quite common, actually).

Comment: Do the PhD students pay their own tuition? Or is it immoral for doctorate students to expect an uncompensated PhD from the university? As you state, 'regulations' are in place, so it would apparently be _legal_ to require 'auxiliary work'. Framing it as a _moral_ question (when the legality seems solid) frankly adds baggage to the question.

Comment: It is most certainly legal, as it's clearly stated in the regulations, the fact is, that if it's immoral, its legality should be reconsidered. Also no, all education in Greece is free (actually paid from taxes) (there are also some private-paid schools and colleges, but most are state run and free).

Comment: @K.Gkinis - the problem is, morality is a value judgement, and is often trotted out as a principle, rather than just owning up to somebody just not liking the situation. There are many situations in every day life where something is expected of you, and is good for the community, without being paid. As Jake points out in his answers, all those (except perhaps #5 depending) are explicit job-related duties of a graduate student at a US university (and good training for a future in academia). Is it immoral to expect students to _take_ exams if they are not paid?

Comment: "Mind that every PhD student that I know, has no official salary from the university". As a fellow Greek, I know that this is simply not true. There are departments that actually pay TAs (PhD students) for this work. It is not very nice to to say things about (y)our country that are not true.

Comment: @Alexandros: unless you know whether or not the departments of the questioner's PhD-student friends pay them a salary, I don't see how you can know whether that statement is true or false.

Comment: @SteveJessop Then the OP should clearly say (at least an estimate) of the number of cases or departments he knows. If he only knows 1-10 such cases, then he should not describe his very incomplete and partial knowledge of reality as the norm.

Comment: @Alexandros Are you sure that they're paid from the university for being PhD students? Or for participating in side research projects?

Comment: Also the cases that I know of, are those in 4 departments in 2 universities (NTUA and Patras). AFAIK the law does not specify a salary for PhD students.

Comment: There is no salary for PhD student in Greece, because it is not considered a job. You are paid for the job you do during your PHD (TA, participating in research projects) and not for doing a PhD. It is obvious you have a misunderstanding of how research funding works.

Comment: @Alexandros Maybe you're right! Being a PhD student is certainly not a job. I thought that research projects fund you in order to reply with a result, and are not guaranteed (you may not recieve one as it is from an outside source), yet your duties are fixed. Thus, you are not paid for your TA duties, you are paid only for providing that result to whoever it interests. (that was my thought process)

Comment: Even the research itself is in many ways work (junior or not, that's beside the point). There are countries where this is recognized as such and courts have even forced university to make no exceptions.

Comment: I find this to be a somewhat curious question: it seems to be limited to Greece, and so far the two Greek academics who have weighed in seem to be differing on the facts.  I'll say this: unless Greek universities are rounding up unwilling people to be their graduate students and/or the conditions of being a Greek graduate student are kept secret, I'm not sure it makes much sense to call the putative practice moral or immoral.  Rather one should ask why the students sign up for such a raw deal...

Comment: ...In that regard, it is perhaps not entirely irrelevant to point out that my  department recently acquired two new Greek graduate students and one new Greek faculty member (who got his graduate degree in England).  If many Greek students not only *can* go elsewhere but *do*, this may have some effect on what is offered to those who choose to stay.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Perhaps they sign up because they need the intellectual stimulation or have certain aspirations. Also if the students (and their parents) have low economic position regardless of the value they provide they can be better taken advantage of economically.

Answer (score 23):

In universities in the USA, the type of work that you describe is typically paid for, with the student being employed as a Teaching Assistant (TA).  In some cases, this is an hourly job; in other cases it comes with a stipend and tuition support. The time a student spends per week varies, but in my experience is most typically averages to 10-20 hours/week (typically lower for hourly wage, higher for stipend).

Many departments do *require* students to spend time as a teaching assistant, under the theory that the work of instruction is an important part of one's education.  It sounds like the universities that you describe are using this theory, but then not compensating the students.

To my mind, whether this is moral or not depends on the nature of the work and the amount of time that is required.

- At one end of the spectrum, if a student is asked to give a couple of guest lectures over the course of a semester, then the experience of preparation and explanation seems like a reasonable inclusion in their educational experience, especially if coached by the professor.
- At the other end of the spectrum, if a student is asked to do 20 hours of grading and other "scut work" that has little educational value, then it is clearly a job for which they should be paid.

Somewhere in between there is some grey area, but in general my feeling is that the more routine and less educational aspects of teaching are *work* for which whoever conducts it should be definitely be compensated.

Comment: It is not really unpaid when the student gets 'free' tuition.  It may be that tuition divided by hours is a low hourly rate...

Comment: This is a good answer, but it leaves one point from the question uncommented: "and may get paid from certain research funds for particular projects that he has to complete/contribute to from outside sources" This could be crucial at least for people who do get paid from such research funds, as there might be certain inofficial assumptions about what recipients of such grants typically do for their money in order to keep the system running.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: right, for a clear-cut example if the grant money says, "this grant includes payment for up to 20 hours a week of scut work for your university, that we're paying on their behalf for you to do" then you can question whether the funding bodies should be paying for scut work, but you can't really question that the scut work has been paid for. I suspect you're right though, and the system runs on expectations rather than explicit conditions.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Indeed, I wrote "inofficial" to express that no such statements will be found anywhere in writing.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: yes, I'm adding that conceivably there might be *official* assumptions too :-) And they might be indirect. The questioner says that these universities state as a condition of being a master's student you must provide auxiliary work (is this a form of "student/apprentice as servant" or a quid pro quo to keep down fees, who knows?). So if the grant says you have to be an enrolled master's student then it might be intentionally endorsing that requirement even without explicitly mentioning it.

Comment: IMHO, the morality of it depends on what you get in return. I would certainly not hesitate to tell my student to grade a quiz while I'm having a severe headache trying to figure out whether some mind-boggling argument in the last version of his thesis is correct or not. On the other hand, using your supervisor power to pass some of your routine duties to the student just because you can is certainly immoral. If you think that your supervisor does a lot for you, I wouldn't make much fuss if he asks you to do some reasonable amount of extra work for him. Otherwise check the written policies.

Comment: Tuition waivers are arguably the least valuable form of company scrip ever produced, given the fact of tuition inflation.

Answer (score 3):

For a related legal perspective, it was recently found (August 2016) by the National Labor Relations Board in the U.S. that graduate students qualify as "statutory employees", have an "an economic relationship to the University", and therefore qualify as being eligible for union membership and collective bargaining with the university over matters such as pay and job responsibilities. So this at least suggests a growing consensus that graduate students are real employees and deserve some consideration as such.

[The Nation -- It’s Official: Graduate Students Can Unionize](https://www.thenation.com/article/its-official-graduate-students-can-unionize/)